# Can you target a Summon creature spell at a creature already in play?

Tags: firetop-mountain

In [Firetop Mountain](http://www.gamerz.net/~fm/Main/index.html) a summon spell has to have a target and that target is the future controller of the creature.

Can you target a summon spell at a NPC creature in play (for example, a goblin) instead of a player? If it is possible, how will it be controlled (i.e. who will direct the new creature)? And what will happen if you target it at an Elemental (that doesn't have a controller by definition)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cast a "Summon Goblin" to a goblin, the newborn baby goblin will inherit his master from the master of the goblin you have targeted to spell to.

If you have a lot of trolls, goblins or Orgres to your order, and that your opponent is about casting a Counterspell, you can choose one of your minion as the target of your Summon Giant, for instance. The new giant will be at your order.

On the other hand, if you cast a spell on a monster belonging to another mage, the other mage will receive this goblin as a gift. Well, jokes apart, this is very convinient in a melee where you have several of your mages involved.

Comment: I may be wrong be I think that a summon spell casts on a elemental will failed. Or maybe, they get married. Hell if I know. Should have a try...

Comment: This is a good trick!